# Spring AOP Configuration for Intercepting All Exceptions

Tags: java, xml, spring, aop

I am struggling to write/configure a ThrowsAdvice interceptor that I want to intercept all exceptions thrown throughout my project:

```
public class ExceptionsInterceptor implements ThrowsAdvice
{
    public void afterThrowing(final Method p_oMethod, final Object[] p_oArgArray,
        final Object p_oTarget, final Exception p_oException)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception caught by Spring AOP!");
    }
}
```

I have already successfully configured a MethodInterceptor implementation that intercepts particular methods that I want to profile (see how long it takes them to execute). Here is the XML config file I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd"/>

<bean name="profilingInterceptor" class="org.me.myproject.aop.ProfilingInterceptor"/>

<bean name="exceptionsInterceptor" class="org.me.myproject.aop.ExceptionsInterceptor"/>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="profilingInterceptor" pointcut="execution(* org.me.myproject.core.Main.doSomething(..))"/>
</aop:config>
```

My ProfilingInterceptor works perfectly and intercepts precisely when my Main::doSomething() method gets invoked - so I known I'm ontrack. Using XmlSpy to look at Spring AOP's schema, it looks like I can add something like the following in order to get my ExceptionsInterceptor to intercept all thrown exceptions:

```
<aop:aspect>
    <after-throwing method=""/>
</aop:aspect>
```

However I cannot find any documentation where this is used as an example, and I have no idea how to configure the method attribute so that its a "wildcard" (*) and matches all classes and all methods.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to aspectJ examples method parameter refers to `@AfterThrowing` advice method:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

  @AfterThrowing(
   pointcut = "execution(* package.addCustomerThrowException(..))",
   throwing= "error")
  public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) {
    //...
  }
}
```

and then the configuration:

```
 <aop:after-throwing method="logAfterThrowing" throwing="error"   />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks and I appreciate the response. You may have very well gotten me 95% of the way there. Just curious though: in the AfterThrowing annotation, the pointcut attribute's execution specifier seems to indicate that you can only have 1 method's exceptions intercepted. I'm looking to have *every* method of *every* class get intercepted when exceptions are thrown. Can you elaborate or point me in the direction of some good literature? Thanks again!

Comment: Frankly, I think the only option you for you is to use @Pointcut("within(org.me.myproject..*)") this will apply advice on every method of package org.me.myproject or its subpackage. I think there is no other way to do it.