# Check if last getter in method chain is not null

Tags: java, design-patterns

In code we have got a lot of chain methods, for example `obj.getA().getB().getC().getD()`. I want to create helper class which will check if method `getD()` isn't null, but before that I need to check all previous getters. I can do it in this way:

```
try {
    obj.getA().getB().getC().getD();
}
catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // some getter is null
}
```

or (which is "silly")

```
if (obj!null && obj.getA()!=null && obj.getA().getB()!=null && ...) {
    obj.getA().getB().getC().getD();
}
else {
    // some getter is null
}
```

I don't want to check it every time using `try{} catch()` in my code. What is the best solution for this purpose?

I think that the best will be:

1. `obj.getA().getB().getC().getD().isNull()` - for this purpose I will need to change all of my getters, for example implement some interface which contains `isNull()` method.
2. `NullObjectHelper.isNull(obj.getA().getB().getC().getD());` - this will be the best (I think so) but how to implement this?

Comment: Solution. Refactor. Don't do chaining #LawOfDemeter

Comment: @user802421 I don't want to refactor whole application, it's to big. All I want to do is to create some helper class. I agree with you that refactor will be the best but we haven't got time.

Comment: I don't see how your two "solutions" would help with intermediate results being `null`

Comment: I want to use it in this way `if (NullObjectHelper.isNotNull(obj.getA().getB().getC().getD())) {} else {}`. If this is bad idea what should I do/use?

Comment: I'm basically with the other commenters, but you might have a look at using AOP, depending on the context. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9211946/687514)

Comment: Migrate to [kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) (if it possible) and enjoy!

Comment: I don't code in java, but while searching for php pages to close as dupes, I arrived here. PHP8 now offers the nullsafe operator: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12351737/2943403 (seems like a case of right solution, wrong language)

Answer (score 10):

As of Java 8 you can use methods like [Optional.isPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--) and [Optional.orElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) to handle null in getter chains:

```
boolean dNotNull = Optional.ofNullable(obj)
              .map(Obj::getA)
              .map(A::getB)
              .map(B::getC)
              .map(C::getD)
              .isPresent();
```

While this is preferable to catching *NullPointerException* the downside of this approach is the object allocations for *Optional* instances.

It is possible to write your own static methods that perform similar operations without this overhead:

```
boolean dNotNull = Nulls.isNotNull(obj, Obj::getA, A::getB, B::getC, C::getD);
```

*For a sample implementation, see the [Nullifier](https://mcdiae.github.io/kludje/artefacts/api/0.6/uk/kludje/Nullifier.html) type [here](https://github.com/mcdiae/kludje).*

No approach is likely to have greater runtime efficiency than nested *if-not-null* checks.

Comment: to do in one line Optional.ofNullable(obj)
              .map(Obj::getA)
              .map(A::getB)
              .map(B::getC)
              .map(C::getD).orElse(objDefault);

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve the desired result with `Option` pattern. This enforces you to change a method signature, but basically if your method returns some type `T`, it guarantees it has some non-null value, and if it returns`Option<T>` it means it either has value T, or null.

Java 7 had some feature called null safety, but it was removed from the final release. You could do:

```
obj?.getA()?.getB()?.getC()?.getD()
```

Moreover, Java 8 will add a feature called `Optional` so you would do it safely.

In fact, if you really want to use that now, try `Null Object` pattern. It means that instead of returning plain `null` you can return some sort of *default* value, which won't trigger NullPointerException. Though, you need add some changes to your getters

```
class Object {
   A getA() {
     // ...
     return a == null ? A.NULL : a;
   }
}

class A {
   static A NULL = new A(); // some default behaviour
   B getB() {
     if (this == NULL) return B.NULL;
     // ...
     return b == null ? B.NULL : b;
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** If you want utility to do it you can wrap it in some functional interface and then call it.

```
static boolean isNullResult(Callable call) throws Exception {
    try {
        return call.call() == null;
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage will be the following:

```
isNullResult(new Callable<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return new A().getB().getC().getInt();
    }
});
```

It won't require you to change existing functionality

Comment: +1 Thanks mishadoff for suggestion. I know that I can use `Null object` pattern but if I will use it I will need to make some changes to application. I don't want to do it because application is almost finished and I'm new in this project.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, **the true solution is refactoring.**

In the meantime, you could just wrap your first workaround in a function:

```
static D getD(MyClass obj) {

    try {
        return obj.getA().getB().getC().getD();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return null; // Or even better, some default D
    }
}
```

At the caller site:

```
D d = getD(obj);
```

At least you don't have to trash the caller with try-catch blocks. You still need to handle the errors somehow, when some of the intermediate `getX()` call returns a `null` and so `d` becomes `null.` The best would be to return some default `D` in the wrapper function.

---

I don't see how the two options you list at the end of your question would help if any of the intermediate `getX()` returns a null; you will get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: To avoid NPE in the last example, we can wrap code in Runnable block and call later with try-catch.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the actual code you've used at all.  It sounds like it's usual for A or B or C to possibly be null, so it's generally a bad idea to go to the expense of throwing an exception in this case.  Wrapping things in a utility method is a good approach, for sure.  However I'd *much* rather the utility method included the "silly" code that does null-checking rather than being lazy and catching exceptions.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle **And I would recommend refactoring in the first place.** Potentially null objects and chained getters are the signs of flaws. My problem with the "silly" code is that it is error prone: it is easy to do a typo there, or miss a null check, etc. We can argue about the pros and cons of the try-catch vs. "silly" snippets but the solution would be to refactor the code so that we don't need any of them... The wrapper function (doesn't matter whether the try-catch or the "silly" snippet is used) at least helps keeping the new codes *relatively* clean; that's my point.

Comment: @Ali Sure, I can agree with all that.  I overlooked the importance of the first line in your answer (you'd think something would have **drawn my attention to it**, but apparently not!).