# Add Spring exception handler programmatically, without @ExceptionHandler annotation (or any other)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

In Spring, I'd like to add an exception handler programmatically, without relying on the system to scan for methods annotated with `@ExceptionHandler`. Is that possible?

Currently, I'm relying on the system to scan for the following method:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handle(
        final HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException httpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,
        final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
{
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
            .body(format(
                    "Unsupported method '%s' for URI '%s'; expected method among: %s.",
                    httpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.getMethod(),
                    httpServletRequest.getRequestURI(),
                    join(", ", asList(httpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.getSupportedMethods())
                            .stream()
                            .map(object -> "'" + object + "'")
                            .collect(toList()))));
}
```

And it works as expected, handling the `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` and serializing the response as expected:

```
Unsupported method 'DELETE' for URI '/example'; expected method among: 'GET', 'POST'.
```

However, I know of no way to, say, use the Java config to indicate that it should use a particular class, or a particular instance, to handle specific exceptions.

I had a similar issue with adding implementations of `ResponseBodyAdvice` programmatically, and there is a way to do that - see here:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ExceptionHandler.class)
public class ConfigurationExample
        extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
{
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter(
            @Qualifier(value = "mvcContentNegotiationManager") final ContentNegotiationManager contentNegotiationManager,
            @Qualifier(value = "mvcConversionService") final FormattingConversionService conversionService,
            @Qualifier(value = "mvcValidator") final Validator validator)
    {
        final RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter = super.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(contentNegotiationManager, conversionService, validator);

        requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setResponseBodyAdvice(Arrays.asList(
                new ResponseBodyAdviceExample()));

        return requestMappingHandlerAdapter;
    }
}
```

Is there a similar method for adding custom exception handlers - or any one?

For background, my goal is to create a library of exception handlers which I can use across projects.

Comment: Is your requirement to handle all the exceptions in different layers in your application ? Spring AOP can be used if you have not already considered the same, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60212599/4214241)

Comment: Interesting, but not what I'm looking for - I only need to handle exceptions produced by Spring Web MVC (and code from ~ the same layer, like serializers / deserializers); the approach you link wouldn't be different from simply using @ExceptionHandler for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is an idiomatic way to do it, but I found a way to add exception handlers programmatically.

(I'll wait a few weeks to mark this as accepted, if anyone wants to offer an alternative.)

Code here:

https://gist.github.com/drewctaylor/f838eb8304d7c526872ed29934a1e830

Ultimately, I subclassed `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`. Under the hood, [`ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.html) essentially maps from `java.lang.Class<java.lang.Exception>` to `java.lang.reflect.Method`; if an exception of the given type occurs, the system returns the given method.

This implementation accepts a list of mappings from `java.lang.Class<java.lang.Exception>` to `java.lang.reflect.Method`. If an exception of a type in that list occurs, it returns the associated method; otherwise, defers to the superclass.

Code for the implementation, `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolverFromList`:

```java
public class ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolverFromList
        extends ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver
{
    private final Map<Class<?>, ExceptionHandlerWithExceptionClassAndMethod<?>> map;

    public ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolverFromList(
            final List<ExceptionHandlerWithExceptionClassAndMethod<?>> list)
    {
        requireNonNull(list);

        map = list.stream().collect(toMap(ExceptionHandlerWithExceptionClassAndMethod::getExceptionClass, Function.identity()));
    }

    @Nullable
    protected ServletInvocableHandlerMethod getExceptionHandlerMethod(
            @Nullable final HandlerMethod handlerMethod,
            final Exception exception)
    {
        requireNonNull(exception);

        return map.containsKey(exception.getClass()) ?
                new ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(map.get(exception.getClass()), map.get(exception.getClass()).getMethod()) :
                super.getExceptionHandlerMethod(handlerMethod, exception);
    }
}
```

The mapping is defined by an implementation of the interface `ExceptionHandlerWithExceptionClassAndMethod`:

```java
public interface ExceptionHandlerWithExceptionClassAndMethod<E extends Exception>
{
    Class<E> getExceptionClass();

    Method getMethod();
}
```

A specific implementation is `ExceptionHandlerForHttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException`, similar to the example in the question:

```java
public class ExceptionHandlerForHttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
        implements ExceptionHandlerWithExceptionClassAndMethod<HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException>
{
    @Override
    public Class<HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException> getExceptionClass()
    {
        return HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Method getMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            return getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                    "handle",
                    HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class,
                    HttpServletRequest.class,
                    HttpServletResponse.class);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public ResponseEntity<String> handle(
            final HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException httpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,
            final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
    {
        return ResponseEntity.status(METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED).body(
                format(
                        "Unsupported method '%s' for URI '%s'; expected method among: %s.",
                        httpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.getMethod(),
                        httpServletRequest.getRequestURI(),
                        join(", ", asList(httpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.getSupportedMethods()).stream().map(object -> "'" + object + "'").collect(toList()))));
    }
}
```

Note that the above combines the mapping with the implementation of the handler, which is not strictly necessary, but presently seems appropriate.

To add the handler to the application, extend the [`Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) from [`WebMvcConfigurationSupport`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html) and override [`createExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html#createExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver--) to return the instance of `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolverFromList`:

```java
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class Configuration
        extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
{
    protected ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver createExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver()
    {
        return new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolverFromList(asList(
                new ExceptionHandlerForHttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException()));
    }
}
```

The application will now use `ExceptionHandlerForHttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` to handle `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException`; for other exceptions, it will use any other handlers defined.